# How to add alternative to program that located in /usr/bin

Tags: linux, bash, debian, symlink, hfs

*Is it possible to substitute binary with same name alternative?* I have `/usr/bin/qtcreator`

I want to use alternative version but `/usr/bin/qtcreator` is binary but not alternative.

What the way I should do this?

Comment: Change order of directories in $PATH variable, so that directory containing alternative appears before /usr/bin

Answer (score 3):

You could place your new qtcreator at `/usr/local/bin/qtcreator`, that location should have preference over `/usr/bin`.

You can check the possible locations for binaries and the order is which they are searched  with `echo $PATH` and you can check which binary will be called with `which qtcreator`

Answer (score 2):

In Bash:

```
$ alias qtcreator="/usr/local/bin/qtcreator"
```

or make sure the path to desired binary is mentioned before the undesired path in `$PATH` *(... as mentioned by others)*.

Comment: Note that `alias`es are only available in interactive shells. Else, use bash functions.

Comment: anishsane, thx, what is interactive shell ? Is it special term for kind of a shell or your own term? And I remembered, I did likely you say, but then it's not able to run aliased qtcreator from bash script.

Comment: That means `alternatives` could not do this work?